# Django: Separate Sessions for Admin and End-User

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have two React frontends (`admin.example.com` and `www.example.com`). My Django backend is located on `backend.example.com`.

Right now I have one `LoginView` for both use cases (admin and end-user). I am using `SessionMiddleware`.

What I want to achieve are two different sessions - so I can login as an admin and have access to `admin.example.com` and separately be logged in into `www.example.com` as a user.

If I set `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.example.com'` I have just a single session for everything.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how could I achieve this? Any best practices? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your server to have two different instances. One that responds to `admin.example.com` with the setting `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN='admin.example.com'` and the other instance responding to `www.example.com` with `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN='www.example.com'`.